# How to increase my program disk Read speed on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, io, disk, disk-io

I have a C++ program `read_bin` to read hundreds of 200MB binary files on disk. The program to read a file using `ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream is(filename,  std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
is.seekg(startPos, std::ios::beg);
int8_t* buffer = new int8_t [bytesToRead];
is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), bytesToRead);
```

I start hundreds of `read_bin` processes in the terminal to read individual binary files concurrently.

e.g.

```
read_bin 001.bin
read_bin 002.bin
read_bin 003.bin
read_bin 004.bin
read_bin 005.bin
...
read_bin 101.bin
```

It's a SSD disk, but I use `iotop` to monitor the read speed is usually at `25MB/s` which is very slow.

```
Total DISK READ :      25.35 M/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:      25.35 M/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       7.84 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND 
 2636 be/4 ubuntu      501.71 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % read_bin 001.bin
 2631 be/4 ubuntu      501.71 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % read_bin 002.bin
 2660 be/4 ubuntu      501.71 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % read_bin 003.bin
 2662 be/4 ubuntu      501.71 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % read_bin 004.bin
 2665 be/4 ubuntu      501.71 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % read_bin 005.bin
 2668 be/4 ubuntu      501.71 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % read_bin 006.bin
```

I can see the IO is full at 99%.

and run `top`:

```
top - 21:36:58 up 10 min,  3 users,  load average: 95.28, 74.89, 37.27
Tasks: 250 total,   1 running, 188 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.2 us,  0.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 74.9 id, 23.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 30875564 total,  5388416 free, 12671052 used, 12816096 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 17743200 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
 2633 ubuntu      20   0  147928 133532   3080 D   0.7  0.4   0:00.73 read_bin 
 2652 ubuntu      20   0  147928 133368   2916 D   0.7  0.4   0:00.72 read_bin 
 2697 ubuntu      20   0  145604 131764   2884 D   0.7  0.4   0:00.69 read_bin 
 2701 ubuntu      20   0  145604 131000   2928 D   0.7  0.4   0:00.70 read_bin 
 2630 ubuntu      20   0  147928 134680   2908 D   0.3  0.4   0:00.72 read_bin 
 2632 ubuntu      20   0  147928 134292   2772 D   0.3  0.4   0:00.72 read_bin 
 2634 ubuntu      20   0  147928 134120   2868 D   0.3  0.4   0:00.70 read_bin
```

I tried to increase buffer `bytesToRead`, but the read speed is still very slow at `25MB/s`. Normally, SSD speed can be fast as `500MB/s`.

How to fix my program to maximize disk READ speed?

Comment: What read performance do you get if you only run one instance of your program?

Comment: Yes, running too many instances of something can make performance much worse.   For example if the disk is being hammered by needing to manage virtual memory for buffering all the reads after you've used up all your physical RAM.  Or from all the context switches.  More workers is NOT always better.  Benchmark 1 at a time, 2 at a time, etc. and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested on google cloud. It's actually their disk performance limits at 25MB/s.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/